# PHP - Looping through an object keys, one cycle per key

Tags: php, foreach

I have this object containing one row and many keys/variables with numbered names. 
I need to pass each of them one at a time to another function. How do I loop through the keys instead of the rows?

The code would look like this:

```
foreach ($object['id'] as $row):
$i++;
$data['myInfo'][$i] = $this->get_data->getInfo('data1', 'id', $row->{'info'.$i.'_id'});`
```

but this obviously won't work since it's looping through the rows/instances of an object, and I have only one row in my `$object['id']` object (with `info1_id`, `info2_id`, `info3_id`, `info4_id`... etc keys), so the loop stops after just one cycle. And I really don't feel like typing all of that extra code by hand, there's gotta be solution for this. :)

Comment: `foreach ($object['id'] as $KEY=>$row){`

Comment: that's a single cycle and doesn't solve anything. I would still need to type everything (a lot) by hand. Please do read again.

Comment: There are no "rows" in arrays. You have dimensions, keys and values.

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate through your object like an array :

```
foreach ($object['id'] as $row) {

    foreach ($row as $k => $v) {
        $id = substr($k, 4, strpos($k, '_')-4);
        $data['myInfo'][$id] = $this->get_data->getInfo('data1', 'id', $v);`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the directions **Alfwed**, I didn't know you could use foreach loop for anything other than instances of an object or arrays (only started learning php a week or so ago), but now it looks pretty straight forward. that's how I did it:

```
foreach ($object['id'] as $row):

        foreach ($row as $k=>$v): 
             $i++;
            if ($k == print_r ('info'.$i.'_id',true)){


            $data['myinfo'][$i] = $this->get_db->getRow('products', 'id','info'.$i.'_id'); 

    <...>
```

in my case, I knew how many and where were those values, so I didn't have to worry about index values too much.

Comment: $row here *is* an object